# How to adjust the delimiters in multline environment

Tags: equations, delimiters

I am trying to have delimiters for the following equation written in `multline` environment, but the right most delimiter is not showing in the output.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc} 
\usepackage{float} 
\hyphenation{multiplicative-multiple} \usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage [numbers] {natbib} 
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
|E(A,M,Q)|\approx \frac{e^{-A}}{1-e^{-A}}+\left|\frac{2^{-Q}e^{A/2}}{\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}} \sum_{q=0}^{Q}(-1)^{M+1+q}\times\\
\binom{Q}{q}\mathcal{R}\Biggl(\frac{\mathcal{M}_C\Bigl(-\frac{A+j2\pi (M+q+1)}{2\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}}\Bigr)}{\frac{A+j2\pi (M+q+1)}{2\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}}}\Biggr)\right|
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: By completing the given code I _do_ see the right most vertical bar, so perhaps it is somehow related to the packages you are including. I suggest you provide a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ok sir..Thank you for your reply....will provide the MWE

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage{float}
\hyphenation{multiplicative-multiple}
\usepackage{amsmath}  \usepackage [numbers] {natbib}   \begin{document} \begin{multline}
|E(A,M,Q)|\approx \frac{e^{-A}}{1-e^{-A}}+\Bigg|\frac{2^{-Q}e^{A/2}}{\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}} \sum_{q=0}^{Q}(-1)^{M+1+q}\times\\
\binom{Q}{q}\mathcal{R}\Biggl(\frac{\mathcal{M}_C\Bigl(-\frac{A+j2\pi (M+q+1)}{2\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}}\Bigr)}{\frac{A+j2\pi (M+q+1)}{2\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}}}\Biggr)\Biggr|
\end{multline} \end{document}

Comment: Please edit the question and post the code there. Also, ensure that this actualy reproduces the problem -- post a screen shot of the result that you get (the code given in the comment, seems to work fine for me).

Comment: Firs version of code works fine, the corrected one, when you insert `\left|`  and `right|` throw error (because they are not closed in the same line of equation). Anyway, your whole equation can be fir in one line ...

Comment: Yes....the problem with first version is that delimiter size is only restricted to \Bigg. I want to have more size , and hence I tried using \left and \right. But in second case there is no right delimiter in output. Also please note that I am writing in two column paper, so due to insufficient space, I have to use multline environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First version of your fragment code works fine, however result is ugly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
    
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
|E(A,M,Q)|\approx \frac{e^{-A}}{1-e^{-A}}+\Bigg|\frac{2^{-Q}e^{A/2}}{\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}} \sum_{q=0}^{Q}(-1)^{M+1+q}\times\\
\binom{Q}{q}\mathcal{R}\Biggl(\frac{\mathcal{M}_C\Bigl(-\frac{A+j2\pi (M+q+1)}{2\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}}\Bigr)}{\frac{A+j2\pi (M+q+1)}{2\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}}}\Biggr)\Biggr|
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(redlines indicate part of page layout).

After your editing of MWE, when you insert `\left|` in the first line of equation and `\right|` in the second, you get error. Each of them had to be closed or opened in the same line. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
    
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
|E(A,M,Q)|\approx \frac{e^{-A}}{1-e^{-A}}+\left|\frac{2^{-Q}e^{A/2}}{\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}} \sum_{q=0}^{Q}(-1)^{M+1+q}\right.\times\\
\left.\binom{Q}{q}\mathcal{R}\Biggl(\frac{\mathcal{M}_C\Bigl(-\frac{A+j2\pi (M+q+1)}{2\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}}\Bigr)}{\frac{A+j2\pi (M+q+1)}{2\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}}}\Biggr)\right|
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

The result is stil ugly:

[image]

From both results followos, that you can write your equation in one line:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
    
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
|E(A,M,Q)|\approx \frac{e^{-A}}{1-e^{-A}}+\left|\frac{2^{-Q}e^{A/2}}{\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}} \sum_{q=0}^{Q}(-1)^{M+1+q}\times
\binom{Q}{q}\mathcal{R}\left(\frac{\mathcal{M}_C\Bigl(-\frac{A+j2\pi (M+q+1)}{2\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}}\Bigr)}{\frac{A+j2\pi (M+q+1)}{2\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}}}\right)\,\right|
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and get far more nice result:

[image]

**Edit:**
In the case, that your document is two columns, that the second example can be written as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn, twocolumn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
|E(A,M,Q)|\approx \frac{e^{-A}}{1-e^{-A}}+\left|\frac{2^{-Q}e^{A/2}}{\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}} \sum_{q=0}^{Q}(-1)^{M+1+q}\times\right.\\
\left.\binom{Q}{q}\mathcal{R}\left(\frac{\mathcal{M}_C\Bigl(-\frac{A+j2\pi (M+q+1)}{2\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}}\Bigr)}{\frac{A+j2\pi (M+q+1)}{2\frac{\gamma_{th}}{\eta^2\bar{\gamma}}}}\right)\,\right|
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But , as I told I do not have enough space to write equation in single line...

Comment: @Saru, sorry, from my answer follow your claim not hold (or my version of `cas-dc` is some how broken).  Anyway, the first and the second example works as you like to have.

Comment: Ok sir...Thank you once again...